# Compatible with my device but empty result on google play

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app released on Google Play and have two devices connected to my play account (phone and tablet). When I open app page on browser it says "This app is compatible with all of your devices" and lists my devices with check marks. I can download on my phone, but on my tablet the Play store return empty result.

**CLOSED**
My bad. This problem was because of regional restriction. Tablet belongs to my sister who returned from another country and apparently her account was registered as from that country. When I switched Google Play account on tablet to my account the app now can be found.

Comment: Did you mark it as tablet compatible app?

Comment: What is your `AndroidManifest.xml` file ?

Comment: @Shailesh there is no need for that anymore, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your app is marked as compatible with tablets, the "all device" phrase usually refers to mobiles.

Check those links:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html#how

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017?hl=en

Comment: as per your second link, I opened Developer Console, went to "Manage devices" and found my tablet in the list (Lenovo MobileLenovo TAB 2 A7-10F– Tab2A7-10F) which is marked as supported device.